# color of list view if affected by color of theme

Tags: android, css, listview, themes

I have define a theme for an activity and the background color here is #67b4ef.

```
  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowTitleSize">100dip</item>
  <item name="android:background">#67b4ef</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">20dip</item>
  </style>
```

this activity has a listview that should be white and I set background for it as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffff">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

but the color of list-view is affected by color of theme background. I don't want this.

listview:

```
             lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Comment: try to set a background to your list item

Comment: you create a parent for this list view and write android:background="#ffffff" code on that parent

Comment: @ShantoGeorge i try it but not works

Comment: @SuryaBondada how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happen because you are using **default android Adapter** .....

Use **Custom Adapter** and change the **List item color**

Use this link [Custom ListView](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html)

If you stuck anywhere in between **Custom ListView** ask here in comment.

enjoy coding.......

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting ListView's background to #ffffff, you should set the background of each item in the Listview to #ffffff.

What happens with your original approach is your ListView background is #ffffff. However, all the item views on the ListView have the default background from the theme (#67b4ef). As a result, the background you see on the screen is the theme background.